# XML Rename all child elements to the same tag name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

I have the following XML document structure.

```
<FareSearchResponse>
    <AirlineList>
        <AQR>...</AQR>
        <ABA>...</ABA>
        <AAI>...</AAI>
        <A9W>...</A9W>
        <AVS>...</AVS>
        <AAF>...</AAF>
        <AEY>...</AEY>
        <ALH>...</ALH>
        <AQF>...</AQF>
    </AirlineList>
</FareSearchResponse>
```

I want to rename all child elements of AirlineList to Airline. The child name tags vary and can be any name. So there is no way of knowing which name tags will appear and what they will be. It is a dynamic XML document from a web service. So far I have managed to load the XML string into an XmlDocument;

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(resultString));
XElement firstChild = xmlDoc.ToXDocument().Root.Elements().First();
```

I want to select all AirlineList elements and rename them to Airline.

I have added a more details. The XML document is now contained in firstChild. How do I replace elements in the firstChild and not directly from XmlDocument

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way in the XML library, but you could use a string and then do string replaces on them. Then serialize back into XML.

Comment: You can use XPath to achieve this.

Comment: @Casey. The children element name tags vary so there is no way of knowing the names of the tags

Comment: @JCM How do I do that?

Comment: What if you just do this: `xmlDoc.InnerXml = xmlDoc.InnerXml.Replace("AirlineList", "Airline");` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select all AirlineList elements and rename them to Airline.

Use `Linq` to `Xml` and update the `Name` for child elements.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("AirlineList").Elements())
{
    element.Name ="Airline";
}
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7VBeh)

Comment: It does not look as easy as you have made it. Suppose I had: XElement firstChild = xmlDoc.ToXDocument().Root.Elements().First(); as the starting point for my xml. How do I replace all elemnts of AirlineList to Airline

Comment: Did you check the `example` Link? Anything I missed?

Comment: As I understand from the question, you want to rename all child elements of a `AirLineList` to `Airline`.

Comment: Yes. But I have made some changes to the XML document and I have eventually ended up cropping the important part of the XML document in the type XElement. It is still the same structure but in a different data type. So how do I replace all children AirlineList to Airline from this data type [ XElement ]?

Comment: How does your modified `Xml` look like?

Comment: It is still the same. I just want to get it from XElement. Hari's answer assumes I am getting it from XDocument. There is no method for Descendants on XElement

Comment: `XElement` has the `Descendants` method, let me update example for you.

Comment: Actually it does. The problem is your foreach loop does not update the document or make any changes.

Comment: It does updates `XDocument`, once changes applied you can use `doc.Save()` to save these changes.

Comment: I want to update the XElement object so that I can write it to XmlTextWriter.

Comment: I have updated example to use `XElement`, please check.

Comment: XElement does not have method Dump()

Comment: Don't use `Dump()` in your code, use `doc.Save()`. It is an extension that dumps output to `Console` for online and other editors.

Comment: This answer worked. It is the way the AirlineList element was being accessed which didn't work for me.